# whats wrong with my jquery radio button?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

hello i am new to jquery can any one please tell me what's wrong with my code

```
   <html>
<head>
<title>jQuery Hello World</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("input[@name='chkBox']").click(function(){
    if ($("#chkBox"]:checked").val() == 'a')
        // Code for handling value 'a'
  {
  $("#msgid").html("This is Hello World by JQuery");
  }

});

</script>
<body>
<input type="radio" name="chkBox" id="chkBox" value="a" />
<div id="msgid">
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: have you even tried debugging? Even the syntax highlight on SO shows that e.g. $("#chkBox"]:checked").val() is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have quite a few things wrong in the script.

- Wrap the checkbox click function within a `$(document).ready( function() { } )` as otherwise it will not be able to see the checkbox being added to the DOM later.
- Please check the error console of your web browser to catch other errors.

Fixed script:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQuery Hello World</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(
                function() {
                $("#chkBox").click(
                    function() {
                        if ($("#chkBox:checked").val() == 'a') {
                            // Code for handling value 'a'
                            $("#msgid").html("This is Hello World by JQuery");
                        }
                    }
                );                                                                                                                                           
                }                                                                                                                                            
            );                                                                                                                                               
        </script>                                                                                                                                            
    </head>                                                                                                                                                  

    <body>                                                                                                                                                   
        <input type="radio" name="chkBox" id="chkBox" value="a" />                                                                                           
        <div id="msgid">                                                                                                                                     
        </div>                                                                                                                                               
    </body>                                                                                                                                                  
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

not just putting it in an onload or domready, there's errors in your syntax and jquery selectors too. see the working fixed version below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQuery Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="radio" name="chkBox" id="chkBox" value="a" />
    <div id="msgid">
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() { //on dom ready
        $('input[name=chkBox]').click(function(){ //syntax corrected
            if ($('#chkBox:checked').val() == 'a')  { //syntax corrected, selector corrected
                $('#msgid').html("This is Hello World by JQuery");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: using anonymous functions directly in jQuery selector is d=not really encouraged.

Comment: using `$(function(){});` over `$(document).ready(function(){})` is discouraged, well not so much discouraged but its not the norm when it comes to jQuery and document states. not a big issue, just a small note.